# Streamlit - txt file upload and parse problem

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I would like to upload a Txt file via streamlit importer and parse it with my "parse function" (tested and works). I have an app.py with parse function:

```
def parse(file, condition, data=[], ind_append=False):
    for line in file:
    ...
return data
```

In app.py I also have main function where I upload my file, but cannot apply my parse function to it successfully.

```
def main():
    file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")

    if file is not None:
        st.write(file)
        data = []
        condition = '5'
        ind_append = False
        with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
            data = parse(f, condition, data, ind_append)

        df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"])
        st.markdown(download_csv(df_2), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Streamlit returns error in line

```
with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
```

Any idea how to write this better? I am successful in running this in Jupyter lab if I have a separate parse.app with my parse function code and separate notebook with below code:

```
        data = []
        condition = '5'
        ind_append = False
        with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
            data = parse(f, condition, data, ind_append)

        df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"])
```

Comment: Can you include  the full error message to your question? That might help to understand what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the complete error but looking at your code:

```
file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
```

is already an opened file, which means you can start iterating through `file` just like any other opened file.
I think you have that error because you are trying to open a file which is already been opened. In this case you **should remove**:

```
with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
```

and proceed with the rest of your operation.

So your code should look like:

```py
if file is not None:
    st.write(file)
    data = []
    condition = '5'
    ind_append = False

    bytes_data = file.getvalue() # Modified
    data = parse(bytes_data, condition, data, ind_append)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps, however now I get another error for data=parse(... line:
"startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str."

Startswith is a part of my parse function.

I tried passing data as bytes but this doesn't resolve an error.
`   if file is not None:
        data = file.getvalue()
        st.write(data)
        condition = '5'
        ind_append = False
        data = parse(file, condition, data, ind_append)`

Comment: Yeah you are at the right path, just go along and  decode the file with `file = file.decode('UTF-8')` so I will edit the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse with [python-stringio/](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/stringio.html)

> Retrieve the entire contents of the “file” at any time before the
> StringIO object’s close() method is called.

```
# with type you restict what file types you expect and you handle for each
file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file",type=["txt",'csv','xlsx'])
if file:
    # this will write UploadedFile(id=2, name='test.txt', type='text/plain', size=666)
    st.write(uploaded_file)
    if file.type=='text/plain':
        from io import StringIO
        stringio=StringIO(file.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))
        read_data=stringio.read()
        st.write(read_data)
```